Identifying SMD chip with a code that contains .F22A?

I'm having some trouble finding the part number for the SMD chip, but I don't see any information on them. I've searched through S manuals. Please help me identify them. It's part of a F701 weight controller.


Here's a broader view of the component and surroundings.

Many thanks for posting the photo!  I see four terminals on that device.  I am wondering if it is a current-sense resistor with Kelvin connections?

It might help to see more of the area around those components, which should make it easier to figure out what they are.

PCB F701 Thanks for your reply. Yes, it appears to be a four terminal current sense resistor using Kelvin connection. But when I measure it with a multimeter on the top I read 20 kilohms and on the bottom I get 0.1 Ohms. Would the component be bad then?

Try measuring it ACROSS instead of lengthwise.

Did you remove UR201, Z2, or were they not stuffed in the first place?

No, the UR201 was not on the circuit.

It is likely a Susumu RM3216 series resistor array with Type A connectivity. Or similar part from other manufacturer.

From the above excerpt we see that same reversed size shape. I estimate ~3.4 x 1.5mm from crude pixel measurements of you image, so that matches the 3216 size roughly.
With the bar and dot marking the pin 1 side alsmo matching. Given the short between the bottom two pins in your picture, that suggests the Type A configuration which has a short between the two resistors on the bar marked side.
It's available in a 1:1 ratio of 10k for each resistor which would match up with your 20k and 0R readings across each long side of the resistor.
They are high precision (0.01%) and high stability resistors which makes sense for the application.
There is no indication of marking codes, but A would match up with the type.

Thank you all for your kind responses. I did the measurements and got 20 kOhms for each arm. It is a 1:1 type A resistor array.

Dwayne's idea that it could be Kelvin connection sense resistors was my first idea (and might be correct), but from the op-amp part number (not a particularly low offset voltage), and the application and the designator, I think they might be matched dual resistor arrays (RA = Resistor Array). This would be appropriate for a precision circuit.
If the two pins on each side of all 4 measures (even in-circuit) close to a dead short then the Kelvin connection is probably right. If not, then trace out that portion of the circuit a bit.

From your measurements, I think there are two matched resistors in that package. The package has 4 terminals, two of which are tied together (indicated by the long white line - maybe - or it could just be an indicator in case the two resistors are different). Just a guess at this point.


The op-amp seems to be connected in a voltage-follower configuration (inverting input shorted with output), with the output connected to this resistor.

I have found Microsemi part numbers matching description and they seem to be voltage suppressors. You can see the details in my answer.

@EdinFifić  Doesn't really look like a match to me, sorry. Both op-amps in the dual package appear to be connected as voltage followers.

I think you're right. RA very likely stands for "resistor array". He just needs to measure them across instead of lengthwise, plus he needs to check them off-board, as other components will affect the measurements.
